# TornadoFX DataGrid not updating

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I'm using TornadoFX in Kotlin and have a `DataGrid` that is linked to an `ArrayList` called `data`, which gets updated. When updating the values in this `ArrayList`, the `DataGrid` is not being updated. I have looked in the documentation for some kind of refresh function as the coupling to the `ArrayList` seems to not be working, but there was nothing.

```kotlin
private var datagrid: DataGrid<Foo> by singleAssign()
private var data = ORIGINAL_VALUE
...
datagrid = datagrid(data) {
    ...
}
...

fun bar() {
    data = NEW_VALUE
}
```

Comment: You need to use an `ObservableList` of some sort.

Comment: @RuckusT-Boom, I've tried using the `FXCollections.observableList` but still no change